# Issue with comparing signature

Tags: java

I am having issue in comparing two signature values. Getting both values as same from logs but entering only else statement.

```
private static final String SIGNATURE = "TLFjqb41Fg+W/qAEw7GMefvr2VY=";

PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
     .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),
          PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
    byte[] signatureBytes = signature.toByteArray();

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");

    md.update(signature.toByteArray());

    final String currentSignature = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.d("REMOVE_ME", "Include this string as a value for SIGNATURE " + currentSignature);
    Log.d("REMOVE_ME", "SIGNATURE as a value for SIGNATURE value:" + SIGNATURE);

    //compare signatures

    if (SIGNATURE.equals(currentSignature)){
        Log.d("REMOVE_ME", "in  IF loop");
        return VALID;

    }else{
        Log.d("REMOVE_ME", "in  else loop");
        return INVALID;
    }
```

Getting logs as:

```
10-13 11:52:27.801: D/REMOVE_ME(16873): Include this string as a value for SIGNATURE TLFjqb41Fg+W/qAEw7GMefvr2VY=
10-13 11:52:27.801: D/REMOVE_ME(16873): SIGNATURE as a value for SIGNATURE value:TLFjqb41Fg+W/qAEw7GMefvr2VY=
10-13 11:52:27.801: D/REMOVE_ME(16873): in  else loop
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, are you sure you really want to return immediately in the `else` block? What's the point of iterating over *all* the signatures (your `for` loop) if you're going to return after looking at the first one. That said, I don't understand why you're getting the log you are...

Comment: There's probably something else going on that an obvious flaw in your code, eg. extra hidden characters like trailing spaces in one of the strings (not in this case, but you get the idea) or you're not actually seeing the code from this run. Perhaps you updated the code but are seeing an old log file?

Comment: Could you give us the original String to run you code ? A simplest example just to test the Digest part with the equals.

Comment: Using a similar code (almost because of Java 6), it works perfectly. Add some trim() to be sure be this is unlikely. Here is the code `String signature = "test";
        byte[] signBytes = signature.getBytes();
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signBytes);
        final String currentSignature = Base64.encode(md.digest());` I run a first time to copy the result into SIGNATURE and run it again.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers.. i have removed the else statement and added trim also.. It Worked..